# SQL Command to convert 12/20/2013 10:33 AM to DATETIME fortmat

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have searched for a SQL command to convert this type of format, but closest I have seen was STR_TO_DATE.  I am at a loss when reading on that.

The situation:

I have a time attendance program that downloads the Names and Timestamps of when employees scan their finger.

There is no option in this program to format the date in the DATETIME format that MYSQL uses, otherwise I wouldn't be here right now.

Instead it stores one column as is "m/d/yyyy h/m AM/PM".

I thought of maybe trying to write a php script that would convert and use Explode for the " " to separate the date and the time, but again I came to a loss when trying to understand STR_TO_DATE.

If I could be pointed in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, found the problem.
$tq="UPDATE `$repd` SET nTime='$newTime' WHERE id=$t1";
there is the alternate apostraphe around $repd and remove the regular apostrophes around $t1 and that worked. Worked with the PHP setup, now to see if I can get the STR_TO_DATE to do it also :)  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE working now.

$tq="UPDATE `$repd` SET nTime=STR_TO_DATE('$t2', '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i %p') WHERE id=$t1";

same thing, only have the alternate apostrophe around $repd, everything else shows as is.  Hope this can help anyone out there who may be having the same issue regarding the DATETIME and apparently now getting UPDATE to work properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be needing

```
 STR_TO_DATE('12/20/2013 10:33 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')
```

This will pick up that particular layout for date and make it into a DATETIME expression.

The trick to understanding STR_TO_DATE is understanding the formatting codes for DATE_FORMAT. You're absolutely right that it's obscure.

See this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

It's quite important to store this kind of time data in a column with the DATETIME data type, because DATETIME columns can be indexed and used for efficient range-scan lookup. Most production systems *always* store this information in DATETIME (or sometimes TIMESTAMP) columns, and translate it upon retrieval to the required display format using either DATE_FORMAT or a host language like php.

If you have an existing table, let's call it "scan", you could add a DATETIME column called "scantimestamp" to it, and then populate it as follows.

```
   UPDATE scan SET scantimestamp = STR_TO_DATE(`Timestamp`, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')
```

That will fix the whole table. Then you can drop the old column.

Do this first on a copy of the table to make sure you don't mess it up, you can copy a table like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE copyscan AS  SELECT * FROM scan
```

You could also do this:

```
  CREATE TABLE betterscan AS 
        SELECT Name,
               STR_TO_DATE(`Timestamp`, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') AS scantime
          FROM scan;

  RENAME TABLE scan TO oldscan;

  RENAME TABLE betterscan TO scan;
```

When you insert new rows into the improved table you can use a prepared statement like this, and your timestamps will be normalized on insertion.

```
  INSERT INTO scan  
        (`Name`, scantimestamp) 
 VALUES (?,      STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')
```

Comment: Might want `%l` instead of `%h` for hours if no leading 0.

Comment: Those leading/no-leading differences only apply to DATE_FORMAT; STR_TO_DATE is more forgiving.  For example, `STR_TO_DATE('12/20/2013 9:3 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')` works fine.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the basic here of STR_TO_DATE.  the %'s on the right is telling STR_TO_DATE how the string is formatted so it knows what to take to then put it in the DATETIME format.  I wasn't as precise with my problem as I should have been.  The part I also didn't understand, was how to call the command (as in I want to change each row in that column to the correct format).
I have 200+ rows with all this wrong format.  the above is specific to that string.  Run a query which selects each row, then updates that row and proceeds?

Comment: An alternative idea:  If I add a new column to the already created table.  set that type to DATETIME.  I can then use either the below answer by Philip G and use the UPDATE MYSQL command to then input the correct format, and just have my pages that call the information to call from the new column.  Any ideas if that is my best option?  Seems like something I could do as I am more familiar with PHP than MYSQL :)

Comment: Whatever works for you is the best thing to do. With this exception: it's much more efficient to search for DATETIME values than arbitrarily-formatted date strings, because they can be indexed.

Comment: I can't count how many times I have come to here and found answers from searching.  The one time so far when I have become stumped, I have received excellent help and it has given me ideas on how to go about this, using your code (and the idea of a PHP automated script thanks to the code below, I am certain I will get this fixed tomorrow).  Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Hi @Ollie Jones,
I am having troubles with STR_TO_DATE still.
Here is my code

$t2=mysql_result($n1result,$n1i,"sTime");
$tq="UPDATE $repd SET nTime=STR_TO_DATE(`$t2`, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') WHERE id='$t1'";

where $n1result is my query to SELECT * FROM `$repd` ($repd being what ever I enter, in my case of testing, 010814, which is an exisiting table.

This is the resulting command sent,
UPDATE 010814 SET nTime=STR_TO_DATE('12/20/2013 10:33 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') WHERE id='1'

however, it keeps coming up false.  I have been racking my brain trying to find out why, but I am lost.

Comment: nTime gets created successfully from your code above,

$cq="ALTER TABLE  `$repd` ADD  `nTime` DATETIME NOT NULL";

and it populated with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for all 221 rows.  Am I missing something??

EDIT: FYI the other apostrophe (beside the 1), is there around the $t2 and $t1 variables in the sql command, just didn't show here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with php DateTime like this:

```
<?php
$date = "09/19/2013 10:33 AM";
//Your timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");

$timestamp = new DateTime("@" . strtotime($date, time()));
$timestamp->setTimezone(new DateTimezone("Europe/Stockholm"));

//echos you specified format
echo $timestamp->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

**EDIT added mysql loop**

```
$sql = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');
$result = $sql->query("SELECT ID, sTime FROM table");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $date = $row->sTime;
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
    $timestamp = new DateTime("@" . strtotime($date, time()));
    $timestamp->setTimezone(new DateTimezone("Europe/Stockholm"));
    //echos you specified format
    $newTime = $timestamp->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    //Updates format for that row
    $sql->query("UPDATE table SET sTime='" . $newTime . "' WHERE ID='" . $row->ID . "'");
}
```

I can't test this right now, but it schould work.

Comment: There is no hint the OP uses PHP.

Comment: Except that he wrote that he had thought about writing a php script using explode, so i made him a less brute force method

Comment: what I would like to do is essentially create a php page, where I type in the tables name, and the php page will then convert every field in the sTime column to the DATETIME format from the incorrect string the attendance program saves the original information as.
If there is a MYSQL command that can do this, that is also an option I will consider.  I just realized though, I do need to change the column type to DATETIME

Comment: Will test out this code and/or alter so that ti fits my application.  Thanks.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my code somewhere.  I have set the new column to VarChar (20) to test with Ollies code, still didn't work.  So i tried with your code, same thing the result is false.  Will post my results when I find out what is going wrong.  I have even moved the Update query far from the alter to ensure time to add the column and then update.

Table exists, column exists.

$t2=mysql_result($n1result,$n1i,"sTime");
$timestamp = new DateTime("@" . strtotime($t2, time()));
$newTime = $timestamp->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$tq="UPDATE $repd SET nTime='$newTime' WHERE id='$t1'";

Comment: @PhilipG Found out what the problem was, see my comments to my original post.  Both methods worked fine in the end once I found the problem.  Thank you.